# Azure Traditional Load Balancer VS Azure Application Gateway response latency?

Tags: azure, networking, load-balancing, windows-server-2012-r2, azure-virtual-network

Environment Details: I have an application hosted in two azure environments for two clients. The application contains ASP.NET web API backend and Angular Frontend. Both applications hosted on two web servers (Windows VM). I'm using LB in the first environment (Environment 1) and using AGW in the second environment (Environment 2).

Problem: The issue that I'm having is, environment 1 API request response time is faster than the environment 2. Below is the screenshot of the browser inspect window for the same request.

According to the timing tab, environment 1 has a fast response time than environment 2.

Question: My question is whether this response time difference due to using LB and AGW?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest difference between Azure load balancer and Azure application gateway is that they works at the different layer at OSI Model. Azure Load Balancer is a high-performance, low-latency Layer 4 load-balancing service (inbound and outbound) for all UDP and TCP
protocols. This might make a quick request and response relatively.

> Application Gateway provides application delivery controller (ADC) as
> a service, offering various Layer 7 load-balancing capabilities. Use
> it to optimize web farm productivity by offloading CPU-intensive SSL
> termination to the gateway.
>
> Azure Load Balancer is a **high-performance, low-latency Layer 4**
> load-balancing service (inbound and outbound) for all UDP and TCP
> protocols. It is built to handle millions of requests per second while
> ensuring your solution is highly available. Azure Load Balancer is
> zone-redundant, ensuring high availability across Availability Zones.

For more references:

- [Overview of load-balancing options in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview)
- [Azure — Difference between Azure Load Balancer and Application Gateway](https://medium.com/awesome-azure/azure-difference-between-azure-load-balancer-and-application-gateway-9a6019c23840)